# How can I keep text of a mat-select fixed on component's border?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-select, mat-form-field

could someone tell how I do a mat-select field text stay fixed on component's border, like this (and put the placeholder too, if possible), even without click on it:

[image]

The default is the text be in middle of component and on click event, the text up to his border:

[image]

My component implementation:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
  <mat-select matNativeControl required>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let age of ages" [value]="age">{{age}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I tried to inspect on Developer tools about the css responsible to format the component on clicked, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `floatLabel` input.

[Check docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormField)

```js
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
  <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
  <mat-select matNativeControl required>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let age of ages" [value]="age">{{age}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

If you want this behaviour in all form fields you can use the `MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` to provide default config.

```
import {MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/form-field';
...

 providers: [
   {
     provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
     useValue: { floatLabel: 'always' }
   }
  ]
```